# Delphi. Копирование текста из TWebbrowser после выполнения JS

Tags: delphi, парсер, webbrowser

Имеется форма с Webbrowser.
Имеется сайт, на котором комментарии к сайтам выводятся с помощью js (mail.ru)
Требуется скопировать весь текст с открытой в Webbrowser страницы после выполнения JS.

Простое копирование HTML кода ничем не поможет - т.к. там нет части текста

Comment: Скопировать лучше в StringList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может, я неправильно понял ваш вопрос, но проблема состоит в том, чтобы получить текст после рендеринга в браузере? Это достаточно просто, нужно обратиться после выполнения кода TWebBrowser'ом к нему как к OLE-контейнеру.

Создадим на тестовом сайте для проверки простой HTML-файл с яваскриптом:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Начало документа...</p>
  <script>
    document.write( 'Привет, Мир!' );
  </script>

  <p>...Конец документа</p>

</body>

</html>
```

На форму бросим TWebBrowser и пишем код:

```
  WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
  str:TStringList;
<...>

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);

// Пишем обработчик события нашего TWebBrowser, которое запустится после выполнения рендеринга
// Обработку ошибок оставлю на вашей совести

begin
  with ASender as TWebBrowser do str.Text:=OleObject.document.body.innerText; // здесь будет результат
end;

<...>

str:=TStringList.Create;
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://мойсайт.com/test_js.html');
```

Наш результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я искал. Спасибо!